# My buttons are working on the first activity but are not being read by the second activity Quiz APP query

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new to `Android Studio` and our teacher asked us to create a `Quiz Application` for our `project`. The problem is that there are 10+ chapters that we have to create and my first idea was to create new `basic activities` pre chapter.

I've tested chapter 1 out and it works fine. but the `buttons` are not working for  chapter 2. They are not checking the questions

- My friend told me to have unique variables for each module. (Both on the layout and on the code)

`Chapter1.java`

```
     private TextView countLabel;
     private TextView questionLabel;
     private ImageView figs;
     private Button answerBtn1;
     private Button answerBtn2;
     private Button answerBtn3;
     private Button answerBtn4;

     private String rightAnswer;
     private int rightAnswerCount = 0;
     private int quizCount = 1;


    static final private int QUIZ_COUNT = 50;

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray = new ArrayList<>();

    String quizData[][] = {
    {"What is salt?","NaCl","Na2Cl2","Na3Cl3","Natl"}; };

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chapter1);

        countLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cc);
        questionLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cq);
     //   figs = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.figures);
        answerBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c1);
        answerBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Content);
        answerBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c3);
        answerBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c4);
        questionLabel.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 0; i < quizData.length; i++) {
            //prep array
            ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][0]); //question
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][1]); //tamang sagot
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][2]); // other naswers
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][3]); // other naswers
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][4]); // other naswers
            quizArray.add(tmpArray);
        }


        showNextQuiz();
    }

        public void showNextQuiz() {

        countLabel.setText("Q" + quizCount);

            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNum = random.nextInt(quizArray.size());

            ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray.get(randomNum);
            questionLabel.setText(quiz.get(0));
            rightAnswer = quiz.get(1);

            quiz.remove(0);
            Collections.shuffle(quiz);

            answerBtn1.setText(quiz.get(0));
            answerBtn2.setText(quiz.get(1));
            answerBtn3.setText(quiz.get(2));
            answerBtn4.setText(quiz.get(3));
    //        figs.setImageResource(image[random.nextInt(image.length)]);
            // Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            quizArray.remove(randomNum);
      /*  FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/
    }

        public void checkAnswer(View view){
            //get pushed button
            Button answerBtn = (Button)findViewById(view.getId());
            String btnText = answerBtn.getText().toString();

            String alertTitle;

            if (btnText.equals(rightAnswer)){
                alertTitle = "Correct Answer!";
                rightAnswerCount ++;
            }else {
                alertTitle = "Wrong...";
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
            builder.setMessage("Answer: " + rightAnswer);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if (quizCount == QUIZ_COUNT)
                    {


                    }else {
                        quizCount++;
                        showNextQuiz();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.show();


        };
```

`Chapter2.java`

```
 private TextView ountLabel;
    private TextView uestionLabel;
    private Button nswerBtn1;
    private Button nswerBtn2;
    private Button nswerBtn3;
    private Button nswerBtn4;

    private String ightAnswer;
    private int ightAnswerCount = 0;
    private int uizCount = 1;
    static final private int QUIZ_COUNT2 = 50;

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray2 = new ArrayList<>();


    String quizData2[][] = {

   {"What is salt?","NaCl","Na2Cl2","Na3Cl3","Natl"}; };


    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chapter2);


        ountLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Content);
        uestionLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uestionLabel);

        nswerBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nswerBtn1);
        nswerBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nswerBtn2);
        nswerBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nswerBtn3);
        nswerBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nswerBtn4);
        uestionLabel.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 0; i < quizData2.length; i++) {
            //prep array
            ArrayList<String> tmpArray2 = new ArrayList<>();
            tmpArray2.add(quizData2[i][0]); //question
            tmpArray2.add(quizData2[i][1]); //tamang sagot
            tmpArray2.add(quizData2[i][2]); // other naswers
            tmpArray2.add(quizData2[i][3]); // other naswers
            tmpArray2.add(quizData2[i][4]); // other naswers
            quizArray2.add(tmpArray2);
        }


        showNextQuiz2();
    }

    public void showNextQuiz2() {

        ountLabel.setText("Q" + uizCount);

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNum = random.nextInt(quizArray2.size());

        ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray2.get(randomNum);
        uestionLabel.setText(quiz.get(0));
        ightAnswer = quiz.get(1);

        quiz.remove(0);
        Collections.shuffle(quiz);

        nswerBtn1.setText(quiz.get(0));
        nswerBtn2.setText(quiz.get(1));
        nswerBtn3.setText(quiz.get(2));
        nswerBtn4.setText(quiz.get(3));
        quizArray2.remove(randomNum);

    }

    public void checkAnswer(View view){
        //get pushed button
        Button answerBtn2 = (Button)findViewById(view.getId());
        String btnText2 = answerBtn2.getText().toString();

        String alertTitle;

        if (btnText2.equals(ightAnswer)){
            alertTitle = "Correct Answer!";
            ightAnswerCount ++;
        }else {
            alertTitle = "Wrong...";
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
        builder.setMessage("Answer: " + ightAnswer);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (uizCount == QUIZ_COUNT2)
                {


                }else {
                    uizCount++;
                    showNextQuiz2();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.show();


    };


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use unique id to each button when you are coding in xml.
for example : for assigning id to a button you can assign it like,

> id:+id/chap2_answer_button_1
>
> id:+id/chap2_answer_button_2

and so on..

For declaring button in java file of an activity.. you can give any name..
that button will only be accessible in a single activity.
Feel free to ask anything..

Comment: chapter 2: android:id="@+id/ch2_a1" yes i've added different ids to my other buttons  Chapter1: android:id="@+id/c4"

Comment: Then what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: I reckoned that it should have worked by now. I've been on my wit's end since last week troubleshooting this.  I've done everything where I had to replace variable names in both XML files and code.

Comment: there might be any other reason than this.. try debugging your code completely.